# Relationship tables concept: check my understanding, please

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I'm designing my first big database and want to check, whether I'm OK in providing tables relationships.

I'm designing a webapp where

1. `users` can play `games` in `teams`
2. each `game` has it's `categories`
3. `users` create their `team` for the `game` and choose their `team` `category`
4. each `game` has it's own subset of `categories` enabled
5. in fact `categories` slightly differ from game to game. For example, there are *slowpoke* categories in *game1* and *game2*, but they differ in alowed time.

How do I hope to store this:

1. there are tables `users`, `teams`, `games`, 
   `categories`, each with it's adequate data fields and `INT primary_key`s
2. there is `user`-`team` M-N relationship table
3. there is `game`-`category` M-N relationship table, with alowed time column
4. there are `category_id` and `game_id` foreign key columns at `team` table

My common queries:

1. user -> all his/her teams, in which they were games, categories
2. game -> all it's categories
3. game -> all teams paticipated, with category, with users
4. game -> all users participated
5. team -> it's game, category

My suggestions to me:

1. Make a real-category id creating a separate INT primary index in `category`-`game` relation table and use it in team table
2. Create separate table with team_id category_id game_id and set all them as a concatenated primary index
3. Just set `game_id` in `teams` table as INDEX

The question is if this thing is OK and what suggestions to accept?

Comment: If you feel all is OK, please leave a comment.

Answer (score 2):

Some thoughts:

- Use `UNSIGNED INT` for primary keys rather than `INT`.
- You must have some TEAM -> GAME mapping, right?

Given that, it seems like you can easily process your "common queries".

What problems were your "suggestions" trying to solve?

Comment: 1. Thank you. This is a good thing to mention. 2. Yep. And I'm just not sure, how to organize that: whether having foreign key in team table or having a special table for team-category-game relationship. 3. Happy to hear that:) 4. Suggestions are presented just to show, in which points of design I'm not sure. They show variants I haven't chosen, but don't actually _know_ why.

Comment: If a game can only have one team, then you can put the team_id in the game table.  If there's more than one team per game, use a mapping table, e.g. game_teams(game_id, team_id).

Comment: The game can have multiple teams, but the team participates only in one game. But I got the concept, thank you:)